# using awk command in for/while loop

Tags: bash, loops, awk

This is the content of my input file(rpm.txt).

```
U25,1007
U27,1269
```

I would like my code to use this file (rpm.txt) as input, change directory to U25, and search for 1007 in U25/test.csv, and print all columns in test.csv that match 1007; and repeat for every line.

This is the code for this, without the loop:

```
cat U25/test.csv | awk -F ',' '$1 == 1007 {print $0}' > x
cat U27/test.csv | awk -F ',' '$1 == 1269 {print $0}' >> x
```

Would anyone be able to help me write this as a loop?

Comment: By the way, you can safely omit `{print $0}` as that is what `awk` does by default anyway.

Comment: Why? Why not just have awk read rpm.txt and then search for 1007 in U25/test.csv, etc. in one invocation of the tool? No cd-ing or shell loops required.

Comment: That's a great idea! Would you be able to help me translate that to a command? I know it would probably use awk -v, but not sure of the final command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some stupid way of doing this without any loops, by creating commands like `grep "^1007," U25/test.csv` and feeding them to shell:

```
sed 's!\(.*\),\(.*\)!grep "^\2," \1/test.csv!' input | sh
```

Comment: This works for me! Would you be able to explain your command a little more to me? Particularly !\(.*\),\(.*\)!

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
while IFS=, read dir num; do
    awk -v num="$num" ... '$1 == num ... '  <"$dir"/test.csv
done <rpm.txt >x
```

Comment: I am not able to get this to work, what am I required to put in the . . . in your command?